# Which machine learning algorithm should I use?

Tags: regression, logistic, svm, bayes

I have one dependent binary categorical variable, and one independent continuous variable.  There is a lot of randomness deciding the result of the dependent variable.

The relationship between the independent variable and the dependent variable is linear.  I have 2,000 data points to train data on. Some possibilities are:

- Logistic regression - simplest option
- SVM (support vector machines)
- Naive bayes
- Random forests - I see this does well on kaggle, but I have a simple
  one variable linear relationship, so it seems random trees isn't
  necessary here.

Comment: It's next to impossible that the binary response is *actually* linear in the independent variable, unless the IV is very restricted in range --- and if it *were* actually linear, why would you use logistic regression? Isn't that nonlinear? Lastly, you state that it's linear with apparent certainty. Where does that certainty arise?

Answer (score 9):

You should try all of the models you listed, and [cross-validate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) them.  It's the name of the site!